# Hey folks, trying to subtract a duration from a time using std::chrono, what am I messing up?

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

So, my code is not compiling, but I would very much like it to. Here's my code:

```
float numSeconds = 50;
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
auto duration = std::chrono::duration<float, std::chrono::seconds>(numSeconds);
startTime -= duration;
```

Seems like it should be pretty straightforward, but I'm getting an operator not found error when attempting the in-place subtraction. Any suggestions?  I've also tried replacing the third line with the following:

```
   auto duration = std::chrono::duration<float, std::ratio<1, 1>>(numSeconds);
```

However, that line doesn't seem to be the cause of the issues, both approaches seem valid. It's my final line still that is unhappy.

Edit: I had a typo in the original code that I posted, so most of the answers aren't relevant to my actual problem. The error code I am getting is on the final line:

```
"Error  C2679   binary '-=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::chrono::duration<float,std::chrono::seconds>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"
```

Additionally, when I change the last line to:

```
timer.m_startTime = timer.m_startTime - duration;
```

I get the following error code:

```
Error   C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock,std::chrono::duration<float,std::ratio<1,1000000000>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: Please add the text of the error message.

Comment: `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()` isn't a `std::chrono::steady_clock`, it's a `std::chrono::time_point`, so I would guess that the assignment in line 2 is failing.

Comment: @NathanPierson Line 2 was a typo on my end when porting the code over, it's not failing there, it's failing at the in-place subtraction, as I said. I added the error message, which supports this.

Answer (score 1):

[Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) [Code Link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7897976c95333161)

### Problems

1. As pointed out in the comments, on Line 2 the return type of `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()` is `std::chrono_time_point`.
2. The 2nd template argument supplied to `std::chrono::duration` doesn't meet the specified requirements. For example you'll notice the compilation error `static assertion failed: period must be a specialization of ratio`  corresponding to that line.
3. Finally, the operator not found is because there is no corresponding `-=` operator for the unsupported template arguments supplied.

### Solution

- You can use std::ratio<1,1> to represent seconds.

```
auto duration = std::chrono::duration<std::int64_t, std::ratio<1,1>>(numSeconds);
 // or simply std::chrono::seconds(numSeconds)
```

- Attempting to use a floating point type for representing time might not be a good idea ([Why?](https://floating-point-gui.de/)). It's a better idea to use a smaller unit(eg. milliseconds instead of seconds), or if you insist on a floating point type you'll need a larger type eg. double(the linked documentation explains this). Something like this seems to get your example working.

```cpp
double numSeconds = 50.0;
using FpDurationT = std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1,1>>;
using TimepointT = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock, FpDurationT>;
TimepointT startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
auto duration = FpDurationT(numSeconds);
startTime -= duration;
```

Comment: Why aren't my template arguments supported? I have a number of seconds, which I need to be specified as a float, not an int. Also, I thought std::chrono::seconds was a valid second parameter? I'm not getting any warnings when defining the duration itself.

Comment: Edited above to answer the first half of your question. As for the 2nd, no,  `std::chrono::seconds` is an alias for `std::chrono::duration<integral type, std::ratio<1,1>>`  - These requirements/definitions are clearly provided in the linked documentation.